# What's wrong with my code that prints structure information?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <ctype.h>

struct ALUMNO{
    int cod;
    char nombre[20], grupo[3], app[20], apm[20];
    float prom,cali[5];
} al[20]={'\0'};

void gotoxy(int x,int y){
    HANDLE hcon;
    hcon = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    COORD dwPos;
    dwPos.X = x;
    dwPos.Y= y;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hcon,dwPos);
}

int main()
{
    char gru[3];
    int x = 0, sw, ac;
    al[0].cod=12345;
    strcpy(al[0].grupo,"1A");
    strcpy(al[0].nombre,"Erick");
    strcpy(al[0].app,"Medina");
    strcpy(al[0].apm,"Ramirez");
    al[0].prom=0.0;

    al[1].cod=12346;
    strcpy(al[1].grupo,"1A");
    strcpy(al[1].nombre,"Emmanuel");
    strcpy(al[1].app,"Sauceda");
    strcpy(al[1].apm,"Perez");
    al[1].prom=0.0;

    al[2].cod=12347;
    strcpy(al[2].grupo,"1B");
    strcpy(al[2].nombre,"Vincio");
    strcpy(al[2].app,"Lopez");
    strcpy(al[2].apm,"Martinez");
    al[2].prom=0.0;
    //salon B
    al[3].cod=12348;
    strcpy(al[3].grupo,"1B");
    strcpy(al[3].nombre,"Bryan");
    strcpy(al[3].app,"Osuna");
    strcpy(al[3].apm,"Beltran");
    al[3].prom=0.0;

    al[4].cod=12349;
    strcpy(al[4].grupo,"1C");
    strcpy(al[4].nombre,"Fullano");
    strcpy(al[4].app,"Mangano");
    strcpy(al[4].apm,"Centenario");
    al[4].prom=0.0;

    al[5].cod=12350;
    strcpy(al[5].grupo,"1C");
    strcpy(al[5].nombre,"Chapo");
    strcpy(al[5].app,"Guzman");
    strcpy(al[5].apm,"Loera");
    al[5].prom=0.0;
    //done

    printf("Grupo: ");
    scanf("%s",&gru);
    gru[1]=toupper(gru[1]);
    system("cls");
    printf("Codigo\tAp.paterno\tap.materno\tnombre\tpromedio");
    for (x=0, sw=0; x<25 && al[x].cod!=0; x++){
        if (strcmp(gru,al[x].grupo)==0){
            sw=1;
            ac++;
        }
        if (sw==1){
            gotoxy(1,ac);
            printf("%i",al[x].cod);
            gotoxy(12,ac);
            printf("%s",al[x].app);
            gotoxy(30,ac);
            printf("%s",al[x].apm);
            gotoxy(50,ac);
            printf("%s",al[x].nombre);
            gotoxy(60,ac);
            printf("%.2f",al[x].prom);
        }
    }
    ac=0;
}
```

For some reason, when you type in the correct group and hit enter, it will print maternal last names on top of others. Or some names maybe missing, or it's just my compiler. It works fine when you only have one name per group.

Comment: For the benefit of others, I've deciphered the variable names based on the header line that gets printed, and "maternal name" is represented by the obvious struct member `apm`.  For some reason, console cursor positioning has been used to present data in tabular form, instead of width specifiers in `printf`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `gru` variable is used wrong in `scanf`.  Should be `gru`, not `&gru`.

By the way, don't use `scanf`, use `fgets`

Comment: While I agree that `&gru` is technically incorrect (it passes a `char (*)[3]` to `scanf()`, but `scanf()` is expecting a `char *`), the actual numeric value passed as the address will be the same.  So, I'm not sure that's the problem.  The `scanf()` is dangerous; it should be using `%2s` to ensure no buffer overflow (or `gru` should be a sane size, like 1024 bytes).